# How test HttpservletRequest with@Context parameter in JerseyTest?

Tags: servlets, mockito, jersey-2.0, grizzly, jersey-test-framework

I have a broken unit test after trying do get the HttpServletRequest that is passed as a parameter in a Jersey Web Service post call:

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("/por/req")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public class MyOwnWs {

@POST
@Path("/confirm")
public Response confirmarRequerimento(
        @ApiParam(value = "Description", required = false)
        final InputJson input,
        @Context HttpServletRequest request) throws MyException {


   Response response = null;
   MyResult result = null;

   String ipAdress = IpUtil.getIp(request);

   // do stuff

   return response;
}
}
```

testing in the browser is fine, the request object contains my test machine ip adress. But int the unit tests with grizzly the request object is always null and I still didn't figured out a way of mocking it. The relevant part of my test code is like:

```
MyResult response = target(URL).
            request().
            post(Entity.json(input), MyResult.class);
```

This was working fine before adding the @Context HTTPServletRequest in the service call. Any Sugestions about what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you use Spring? Can you show class definition & annotations

Comment: @user7294900 just CDI, and I edited the post with the class definition.